# AWS::S3::Errors::InvalidAccessKeyId + Paperclip + Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

This is my paperclip config inside `config/environments/production.rb`

```
# Paperclip
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  storage: :s3,
  s3_credentials: { bucket: Rails.application.secrets.aws_bucket, 
                    access_key_id: Rails.application.secrets.aws_access_key_id,
                    secret_access_key: Rails.application.secrets.aws_secret_access_key },
  s3_host_name: Rails.application.secrets.aws_host_name,
  url: ':s3_domain_url' }
end
```

It works perfectly while I am on `localhost` with AWS credentials.

I switch to my server in production, use the SAME config and the SAME credentials and I get an:

```
[AWS S3 403 0.188842 1 retries] put_object(:acl=>:public_read,:bucket_name=>"<bucket-name>",:content_length=>87882,:content_type=>"image/jpeg",:data=>Paperclip::UploadedFileAdapter: profile_picture_square.jpg,:key=>"assets/users/1/original.jpg") AWS::S3::Errors::InvalidAccessKeyId The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
```

Where `<bucket-name>` is actually the name of my bucket.

Why is this happening ?

Comment: can you add your development.rb file ?

Comment: @NelsonPatricioJimenez can'd added it here because it is too long.

But it is the rails default plus the email config and this paperclip config above.

Comment: Check that the access key is in production section of secrets.yml.

Also print the access key in logs right before uploading image. Or just print it on a page somewhere. I'm sure that the key is different (or maybe even not set).

Comment: @Jeiwan I open the rails console on the server, ran `Rails.application.config.paperclip_defaults` and the credentials are there.

Comment: @jbernardo Do you run console with `-e production`?

Comment: @Jeiwan That was it !

Comment: @Jeiwan It was not loading the credentials correctly.
I entered in the rails console on the server and the credentials were ok, but not in the server process, a simple puma restart did not work, I had to show down the server and start it again in order for it to work
Many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you try using an env file?

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => {
  :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
  :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
  :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  }
}
```

Comment: I opened the rails console on the server and checked if the values were being loaded (by running Rails.application.secrets.<secret>) and they seem to be fine.

Comment: Although, I tried using env vars now and I still get the same error